# How to install a thermostat for electric heat?

Tags: electrical, wiring, thermostat, heat

I have a 240v electric heat in my house. I’m trying to switch my thermostat from an old Mears to a new Mysa smart thermostat. I have six wires coming from the gang box. 1 set is to the heater( load) and 2 sets are hot( lines). How can I connect my wiring to the new thermostat? I have a double 20A breaker.
Tech support is telling me to connect my 2 black line wires together and run them to L1. Seems like a disaster to me. Any thoughts? The new thermostat has Load, L1, L2.

Comment: Do you know how the wires were connected to the old thermostat? Pictures?

Comment: I cant paste a pic to comments.

Comment: [edit] the question to add pictures using the "sun and mountain" icon. FWIW, it seems perfectly normal, not "a disaster" to have one set of hots feeding more than one thermostat - or one thermostat controlling two heaters. Which is why it matters how the orignal thermostat was wired...

Comment: If you're having trouble getting the pics added, just paste the links down here in the comments and someone will edit them in for you.

Comment: Is there more than one base board heater fed by the circuit? I looked at the instructions for wiring it and I'll agree it was confusing. You may have "power-in, power-out, switched power to the baseboard". Based on the install instructions, I suspect it's a single pole stat even though 240v (which I hate), much safer to turn off both legs when the tstat isn't calling for heat. But I'm not sure, you're mileage may vary!

Comment: I checked the 2 lines coming from the electrical box, they are 120v each. Tech support is telling me to combine the 2 phases and connect to L1 ( which is a single line coming from the new thermostat. P.S. only 1 heater.

Comment: @Adam, can you please get us those photos of the innards of the box?